# std::vector and its initialization pointer consistence

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, stl

I give the following codes to illustrate my question, and you can them in http://cpp.sh/

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  int *p;
  p = new int [10];
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
      p[i] = i;

  std::vector<int> vecArray(p,p+10);
  vecArray[3]=300;

  for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
      std::cout<<vecArray[i]<<std::endl;

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
      std::cout<<p[i]<<std::endl;

  delete []p;
}
```

From the codes we can see that after the pointer `p` is used to initialze the vector `vecArray` then when the content of the vector is changed it will not affact the content in the pointer. My question is: how could it be possible that content of the vctor is always the same with the pointer?

Comment: Do you want the value in `p[3]` to change after `vecArray[3]=300;`?

Comment: All container classes store hard copies of data, or they would be rather useless.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall Yes.

Comment: The very *point* of `vector<>` is its ability to dynamically resize if you add elements. If it needs more memory, `vector<>` allocates new memory for the data it contains, *copies the old data to the new memory location, and releases the old memory*. It should be clear that at this point *there is no way that the `vector<>` still refers to the same memory as `p`*, even if you managed to set them up like that originally. --- I suspect we are looking at a X-Y problem here. What is the **original problem** that you're trying to solve with this vector-referring-same-memory-as-array as a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The content of the vector is a copy of the content of your dynamically allocated array.

You need to understand that your sample code allocates 10 integers **TWO** times, one time when you explicitly call `new` and the other one when you construct your `vector`.

You can have both sharing the same memory by, for example, first building your vector and then getting a pointer to its data :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int     main(void)
{
  std::vector<int> vecArray(10);

  for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    vecArray[i] = i;

  const int* p = vecArray.data();

  vecArray[3]=300;

  for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    std::cout<<vecArray[i]<<std::endl;

  for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    std::cout<<p[i]<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: One should note that neither the pointer to the internal data returned by `vector::data()` nor iterators are guaranteed to be valid after some operations on the vector (e.g., insertion) due to reallocation.

Comment: Be aware that `p` can point to invalid memory when `vecArray` is modified, e.g. by adding new elements.

Comment: @Drax Thanks, it is a nice solution. But in my case, I want the vector share the pointer. In your example, it is the pointer that shares the vector.

Comment: @feelfree You can't do that, `vector` manages its own memory not one you already created yourself somewhere else (except maybe with custom allocators, but not sure that's what you want) :)

Answer (score 2):

You can make your `vector` contain pointer to `int`.

You push in your vector addresses of your dynamic allocated array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  int *p;
  p = new int [10];
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
      p[i] = i;

  std::vector<int*> vecArray;
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
      vecArray.push_back(&p[i]); //push_back addresses in the vector

  p[3]=300; //you can also: *(vecArray[3])=300;

  for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
      std::cout<<*vecArray[i]<<std::endl; // Deference your pointer to get the value

  for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
      std::cout<<p[i]<<std::endl;

  delete []p;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the constructor of `vector` that uses a range

`template <class InputIterator> vector (InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
                 const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());`

And this is the description:

`Range constructor: Constructs a container with as many elements as the range [first,last), with each element emplace-constructed from its corresponding element in that range, in the same order.`

it says e`mplace-constructed` from its corresponding element. So it means it create a new copy of the object pointing by the pointer.

That's why `The underlying type an std::vector uses must be CopyAssignable`

So as the summery vector create set of copies from the array element. So if you change any of a element from one set, it doesn't reflect in other set.